# Hydrostatic force on a dam

Tags: physics

A dam is inclined at an angle of 30° from the vertical and has the shape of an isosceles trapezoid 200 ft wide at the top and 100 ft wide at the bottom and with a slant height of 160 ft. Find the hydro static force on the dam when it is full of water. ( Recall that the weight density of water is 62.5 lb/ft3.)
The answer for this question is 83,354,954 lb but I get something else.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a simple integration. What did you do?

Comment: $$62.5\int_{0}^{160}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left ( 100+\frac{5x}{8} \right )\left ( 160-x \right )dx$$  @almagest

Answer (score 1):

We fought with this one.

To get the quoted numerical answer it is necessary to take **160** to be the length of the **long (diagonal) edge of the inclined trapezoid**. 
(Ambiguous use of *slant height*, perhaps).  What I normally think of as the slant height is then $A=\sqrt{160^2-50^2}$, and the vertical height is $H=A cos(30)$.

Let's model good problem solving by drawing it.  (Drawings are tools).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QklQv.jpg

Then **mike**'s integral becomes:

$$F = 62.5\int_{0}^{A}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left ( 100+\frac{100}{A}x\right )\left ( A-x \right )dx,$$  where
$$A=\sqrt{160^2-50^2}.$$
Or alternatively as a vertical integral: 
$$F = 62.5\int_{0}^{H}y\left ( 200-\frac{100}{H} y\right ) \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}dy$$ 
where
$$ H=\sqrt{160^2-50^2} cos(30).$$